# Adressing a fileupload within a repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

So i have my fileupload within my repeater

```
  <asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="content" Runat="Server">
<asp:Repeater ID="rptVrijstellingen" runat="server">

        <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
        <h2><%# Eval("tblExternVak.ExternvakNaam") %></h2>
        <h4>Selecteer een bestand om te uploaden:</h4>
       Gelieve het bestand de naam te geven van het overeenkomstige vak om de verwerking 
           vlot te laten verlopen.

           <br /><br />  <br />
           <asp:FileUpload id="FileUpload1"                 
           runat="server">
           </asp:FileUpload>
       <br /><br />
       <hr />
       <br />
         <br />
        <asp:Button id="UploadButton" 
           Text="Upload file"
           OnClick="UploadButton_Click"
           runat="server">
       </asp:Button>     
       <br />    
    <br />
            </ItemTemplate>
        <SeparatorTemplate><hr /></SeparatorTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>    
       <asp:CheckBox id="CBupload" runat="server" />
       <asp:Label id="lblUpload" runat="server"> Geleverd aan Mevrouw Van Orlé</asp:Label>
       <asp:Label id="UploadStatusLabel" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>   
</asp:Content>
```

And i want to adress it from my classfile

```
   if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {

            String fileName = FileUpload1.FileName;
            savePath += fileName;
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(savePath));
            tblBijlage s = new tblBijlage();
            s.bijlageTitel = fileName;
            s.bijlageURL = savePath;
            s.bijlageType = "1";
            s.fk_externvakID = 2;
            BLLstudent BLLstudent = new BLLstudent();
            BLLstudent.insertFile(s);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            UploadStatusLabel.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
    else
    {
      UploadStatusLabel.Text = "Gelieve een bestand te kiezen";
    }
    }
}
```

The problem is it doesnt find fileupload1 and any other declared stuff within the repeater, can anyone present me a solution on how to adress the upload within the repeater? (I fill up the repeater with data in my page_load so it exists on load so i know that is not the problem)

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to iterate the Items collection of Repeater control and use `FindControl` method to get the reference of `FileUpload1` object.

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptVrijstellingen.Items)
 {
    FileUpload file=(FileUpload)item.FindControl("FileUpload1");
    String fileName = file.FileName;
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(savePath + fileName));
    ....
  }
```

Comment: could you give a small example plz? I am kinda new in c# :$

Comment: Tyvm very nice wich i could give you a +1 but im new :(

Comment: @ToonVanDooren - Thanks! Have a look at Meta - FAQ  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Use `rptVrijstellingen.Items[rowNumber].FindControl("FileUpload1") as FileUpload` where `rowNumber` is a number of a row you want to access.